# Laravel, custom functions in for views

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am having someone create a bunch of templates (themes) for a website, and want to keep data passed to the views flexible.

For example, with the users in the system I want to be able to supply the top x users and the most recent x users. In my controller I don't want to pass this data to the view, because he might just need the top 5 users and I am querying the top 10 - or worse, I might only get the top 5 and he wants the top 10.

I am thinking there would be two ways to do this.

1 - A view "helpers" file, which could contain functions like. `getTopUsers($count)` and `getNewestUsers($count)` which would do the model / repo call.

2 - Create a view presenter to keep these extra functions. I've had a look and there seems to be two main presenter packages - https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter and https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter

Maybe there is a better way?

There could be half a dozen of these, for various models...

Answer (score 0):

I would pop some client side code into your views and access a route to a controller action (which returns JSON by default) and conditionally add that particular snippet into your view (via a variable passed to the view that determines if the person is logged in). Then you can apply an auth filter to your route to protect it.

Note: with this approach you can pass url parameters to your action. This means you can tell your controller to limit your results more easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question, my friend. What I can think of is the following

1) cheap way, just query 10 or whichever the biggest number, and then pass a variable $count to the view or let view pass a variable to the sub view

2) api call, if you'd like to do AJAX call, then as others suggested, you could just design a new route, getData?count=5.

Normally it's not easy to meet all requirements, and practically speaking in the prototype stage, it'll be more cost-effective to write fixed function like getData5, and getData10, or just make two pages :) it'll be a lot faster than coming up another new architecture design and then realize in the end nobody really uses them.